# Where is the target all-recursive in makefile?

Tags: makefile

In a makefile, I got the target `all` and its dependency `all-recursive`.

I search the whole Makefile, but I don't see `all-recursive` defined. I think `all-recursive` must also be a target, or how can make execute

```
all: $(BUILT_SOURCES)
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-recursive
```

I don't see the definition of `all-recursive`.
if I delete it, the make program will continuously deal with the all target. Is `all-recursive` built-in?

Comment: It's in there.  You're just not finding it.  It may be in a variable which is then used as a target.  There is no explicit target that is built in to make (except the special pseudo targets like `.DEFAULT` etc.) so it's definitely in your makefile.  You can, if you prefer, use `make -p` to print out make's internal database.

Comment: It might also be in something that's `include`d, though, so it might not be directly in the `makefile`... Also, if `$(AM_MAKEFLAGS)` includes something like `-C <some_directory>`, it'll be in that `makefile` instead, or if it includes `-f <some_alternate_makefile>`, then you'll need to look there. Same thing applies if `$(MAKE)` contains possible options to `make` instead of just `<path_to>/make`...

Comment: lol I was finding the same exact question because of the same exact Makefile recipe. I know it's because autogenerated but still :]

Answer (score 34):

I spent hours finding them too. No, it's not a built-in feature of `make`; it turned out that this is a characteristic of Autotools-generated Makefile.

Those `THING-recursive` targets are actually defined in that very Makefile, but in a complicated way that you cannot use simple `grep` to find them.

It starts from `RECURSIVE_TARGETS` variable definition in the Makefile, which goes like this:

```
RECURSIVE_TARGETS = all-recursive check-recursive dvi-recursive \
    html-recursive info-recursive install-data-recursive \
    install-dvi-recursive install-exec-recursive \
    install-html-recursive install-info-recursive \
    install-pdf-recursive install-ps-recursive install-recursive \
    installcheck-recursive installdirs-recursive pdf-recursive \
    ps-recursive uninstall-recursive
```

Followed by a real definition of those targets somewhere below:

```
$(RECURSIVE_TARGETS):
    @fail= failcom='exit 1'; \
    for f in x $$MAKEFLAGS; do \
      case $$f in \
        *=* | --[!k]*);; \
        *k*) failcom='fail=yes';; \
      esac; \
    done; \
    dot_seen=no; \
    target=`echo $@ | sed s/-recursive//`; \
    list='$(SUBDIRS)'; for subdir in $$list; do \
      echo "Making $$target in $$subdir"; \
      if test "$$subdir" = "."; then \
        dot_seen=yes; \
        local_target="$$target-am"; \
      else \
        local_target="$$target"; \
      fi; \
      ($(am__cd) $$subdir && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $$local_target) \
      || eval $$failcom; \
    done; \
    if test "$$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) "$$target-am" || exit 1; \
    fi; test -z "$$fail"
```

Which resolves into this:

```
all-recursive check-recursive dvi-recursive \
    html-recursive info-recursive install-data-recursive \
    install-dvi-recursive install-exec-recursive \
    install-html-recursive install-info-recursive \
    install-pdf-recursive install-ps-recursive install-recursive \
    installcheck-recursive installdirs-recursive pdf-recursive \
    ps-recursive uninstall-recursive:
        @fail= failcom='exit 1'; \
        for f in x $$MAKEFLAGS; do \
          case $$f in \
            *=* | --[!k]*);; \
            *k*) failcom='fail=yes';; \
          esac; \
        done; \
        dot_seen=no; \
        target=`echo $@ | sed s/-recursive//`; \
        list='$(SUBDIRS)'; for subdir in $$list; do \
          echo "Making $$target in $$subdir"; \
          if test "$$subdir" = "."; then \
            dot_seen=yes; \
            local_target="$$target-am"; \
          else \
            local_target="$$target"; \
          fi; \
          ($(am__cd) $$subdir && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $$local_target) \
          || eval $$failcom; \
        done; \
        if test "$$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
          $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) "$$target-am" || exit 1; \
        fi; test -z "$$fail"
```

This target's recipe's is essentially a boilerplate code to loop through each subdirectory found in current folder and start `make` inside it, using the same target name but with "-recursive" stripped out.

Note that these `THING-recursive` targets are not meant to be called directly by user; it will be run automatically as a part of normal `THING` target (without "-recursive"), as a mechanism to trigger same-target building in subprojects' tree.

Addendum: The example code is taken from configured root Makefile of [GNU Flash Player](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) (version [e9eb84e](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnash.git/tree/?id=e9eb84e128f7f0ba4558d00cf794027bf9125a7d)).

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.  Thanks for the deep dive into autotools!

Answer (score 2):

see if it is inclusively defined in the target $(RECURSIVE_TARGETS)